# Django: unknown database name

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, visual-studio

I am trying to change the database in django from sqlite3 to mysql

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django',
        'USER':'myusername',
        'PASSWORD':'mypassword',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'3306',
    }
}
```

and after trying to run my server i get this error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 244, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'django'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run      
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 576, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 244, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 123, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ыв\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 185, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'django'")
```

i dont know why django can't see my db, maybe you guys have some ideas.

Mysql didn't get me any problems before this case,
i haven't found a way to fix an error, so I counting on your help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you re-run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands after switching to the new database?

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer to that is that `django` database ist't crated in MySQL. Django will not create the database for you like it do on `sqlite3`, you have to had this database created before.

You can ensure that you created the database by running a command like that:

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -pmypassword -u myusername # to connect on your mysql
mysql> show databases; # list all databases on your MySQL server
```

To create a new database my recomendation is the following:

```
mysql> create database django charset utf8mb4; -- charset is optional
mysql> use django;
```